# Checking if username is available

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to check if the username is available before i insert into the table.

But it seems to insert into the table no matter if the username already exists.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
define('DB_NAME', 'madsanker_dk_db');
define('DB_USER', 'madsanker_dk');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'myPassword');
define('DB_HOST', 'mysql43.unoeuro.com');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
 die('Could not connect: ' .mysqli_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db( $link, DB_NAME);

if (!$db_selected) {
 die('Could not connect: ' .mysqli_connect_error());
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$password);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$name);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$email);
$password = md5($password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mainLogin WHERE username = '$username'";
    
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count > 0) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO mainLogin (username, password, name, email)  VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$name','$email' )";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (!$result) {
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}else {
    $_SESSION['login'] = $username;
  echo "<script>window.location = 'http://madsanker.dk.linux101.unoeuro-server.com'</script>";
}
}else {
    echo "username taken";
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not inserting? Any error?

Comment: have you var_dump(); your $result and $count ? what will you get in it ?

Comment: Just check `if($count ==0) {`

Comment: If username already in db than why this `if($count > 0) {` why not this `if($count <= 0) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the greater sign in your if statement from ">" to ==0

```
if($count==0){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `username` already in db than change this condition:

```
if($count > 0) {  
  //your stuff
}
```

With:

```
if($count <= 0) { // if not found
   //your stuff
}
```